# How to log the "path taken" by the code and its exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a requirement of compose the log message through the path taken by a code in a user click. Let me give an example:

Imagine the classical example: A user clicks in a button in a View, that calls code from the Business Layer that call code from Data Access Layer, that returns data to the Business, that return to a View.
I want to compose my log message through these layers. The caller method (in a View) that started the whole process will receive the full message. Here are some code sample just to help me explain what i am trying to achieve.

```
public void ViewMethod()
{
    try
    {
        BussinessMethod();           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Logger.Enqueue("exception occured");
         Logger.Print();
    }
}

public void BussinessMethod()
{
    try
    {
        DataAcessMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Logger.Enqueue("exception occured in the bussiness method")
    }
}

public void DataAcessMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // some code that executes an SQL command
        // Log the SQL Command 1
        // Log the SQL Command 2 and do on...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Logger.Enqueue("Error occurred, sqls executed are ...", sqlExecuted);
    }
}
```

`EDIT:` The reason i am needing it is that i need to log all the SQL's executed in the whole process. If an error occurs in any point of the whole process, the user cant be warned, i need to store as much as possible information becouse the support technician will need it later.

My question is if there is any design pattern to develop it or passing a Logger  reference across the "layers" are acceptable?

Comment: You can create a context class and set it on the thread. Or, some property that can be thread-static. But really, why don't you just catch exception in `ViewMethod`? Lets say, `DataAcessMethod` fails. It doesn't even make sense to keep executing in  `BussinessMethod`. In `BussinessMethod` try catching exception related to its code. And do nothing to exception propagated from data layer

Comment: IMHO, `Logger` (whichever you use) isn't just for exceptions - they have "levels", one of them is `Info` (informational logging).

Comment: Do you care about the stacktraces or do you just want to log messages?

Comment: @T.S. The reason i formulated the question in that way is that i want to log the sqls executed in the whole process.

Comment: @JohanP Stack traces are very useful to me.

Comment: @EdSF Thanks, do you know some easy way of `grouping` the messages of some "bussiness process" like the one described in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
public class Context
{
     [ThreadStatic]
     private static LogStore _store; 

     public static Log(....)
     {
         .....
     } 
}
```

---

```
public void ViewMethod()
{

    var response = BussinessMethod();           
    if (response.Status = ResponseStatus.Success)
        // do something with response.Data
    else
        // show message?
}

public BusinessMethodResponse BussinessMethod()
{

    var response = new BusinessMethodResponse() {Status = ResponseStatus.Failure};
    SomeData data;
    try
    {
        data = DataAcessMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Context.Log(....);
        response.Message = "Data retrieval failed";
        return response;
    }
    try
    {
        // massage the data here
        response.Status = ResponseStatus.Success;
        response.Data = myMassagedData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Context.Log(....);
         response.Message = "Something failed";
    }

    return response;
}

public void DataAcessMethod()
{
    // some code that executes an SQL command
}
```

What this do? Now you can call your business objects from MVC, WPF, WinForms, Web Forms, etc...

Comment: Be careful about ThreadStatic for MVC or Web Forms.  ASP.NET has a feature called Thread Affinity that allows under some circumstances for a web request to start processing on one thread and switch to another.  I have seen production cases of this happening on a system under load and ending up having data that was put into ThreadStatic members "for efficiency" exposing one user's data to another.  Granted it's an edge case, but better to go that route knowing the risk than be taken by surprise.

Comment: @KyleBurns agree. but I think, it doesn't affect direct chain of calls.

Comment: If something ended up waiting for I/O (like a database or service call), that's when under load the thread could be selected for suspension and then resume on another thread after completion of the blocking call. That was a lesson learned the hard way...